# Initialising Python properties

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, properties, psycopg2

I'm writing a Python class to manage a Postgres database connection using pyscopg2.

I'd like the class to set up a connection to the database upon initialisation (I feel like this *might* be a terrible idea, but I can't think of a good reason why).  I'm trying to make this work with a property, which I've never used before.  In other words, I want the getter to be called from within the `__init__` method.

My class looks something like this:

```
class MyDatabase:
    connection_string = "host='<host_ip>' db_name='<db_name>'"

    def __init__(self):
        # *
        self._connection = connection

    @property
    def connection(self):
        # Check for an existing connection
        if self._connection:
            self._connection.close()
        self._connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
        return self._connection

    ...
```

In this version, the check for an existing connection throws `AttributeError: Elefriends instance has no attribute '_connection'`, which makes sense.  I can get around this by simply adding a line that says `self._connection = None` at the place I've marked with `# *`, but this feels clunky.  Is this the price I pay for the convenience?  Am I just being fussy?  Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You really want a fresh connection *every time* you ask for the connection? Just set it as a regular attribute in your `__init__` and forget about it.

Comment: `if hasattr(self,"_connection")` but I'd say that'd be worse.

Comment: but i really got to agree with Kindall, are you really sure it should make a new connection every time the property is accessed?

Comment: The idea is that the connection getter will only be used to initialise the connection, or if something has gone wrong with it.  I might even make it "[private](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)".  Normally I would plan to just use methods along the lines of `fetch(query_string)` and not worry about the connection.  Is this a poor design pattern?  I guess I could have a separate method to initialise the connection, and another one to close it and return a new one, but that's even messier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the if ... statement, you could use:

```
try:
    self._connection.close()
except AttributeError:
    pass
self._connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
return self._connection
```